# What happens to Teresa in The Death Cure?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In the ending scene of *Maze Runner: The Death Cure* we see Teresa's name is carved into the stone and she is not visible at the ending - so what really happened to her?

Comment: Your title mentions what happens _after_, but the body mentions what happened presumably before, could you clarify what you meant? The latter is fine, but the "after" option might be closed as primarily opinion-based (actually, it _was_ closed and deleted as POB when you asked it [a while ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193203/98028))

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMhLSQDDtkQ

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be sure to edit it

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed some part of the movie! In the end, Teresa takes herself and the wounded Thomas to the roof of the building in attempt to get rescued!  Thomas barely made it to the aircraft but unfortunately Teresa couldn't (it seemed like she didn't even try because of her guilt) as the building collapsed!

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this such as video clips or screenshots to support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_Runner:_The_Death_Cure
>
> With the building on fire, Thomas and Teresa escape to the roof. The rest of the team arrives on a Berg. Teresa helps Thomas on board, but the building caves in, causing Teresa to fall to her death.

> Maze Runner 3: The Death Cure | Teresa's Death Scene

> Minho: Come on!
>
> Vince: Reach!
>
> Teresa: (launches Thomas on to the Berg ramp) Go!
>
> Pause on Teresa, then she falls off screen as the building collapses
>
> Thomas: Noooooooooo!